# Sphinx-doc :automodule: with Mock imports

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm attempting to use sphinx-doc :automodule: in conjunction with Mock-ed out modules as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912502/754456) answer. Specifically I'm using Mock for PyQt5 module imports which are not available on ReadTheDocs.

Strangely, I'm finding that any class that inherits from a Mock-ed module's class is not included in the resulting documentation. It appears as though sphinx-doc can't *see* them for some reason.

My slightly-custom Mock is as follows:

```
from mock import Mock as MagicMock


class Mock(MagicMock):
    __all__ = ['QApplication','pyqtSignal','pyqtSlot','QObject','QAbstractItemModel','QModelIndex','QTabWidget',
        'QWebPage','QTableView','QWebView','QAbstractTableModel','Qt','QWidget','QPushButton','QDoubleSpinBox',
        'QListWidget','QDialog','QSize','QTableWidget','QMainWindow','QTreeWidget',
        'QAbstractItemDelegate','QColor','QGraphicsItemGroup','QGraphicsItem','QGraphicsPathItem',
        'QGraphicsTextItem','QGraphicsRectItem','QGraphicsScene','QGraphicsView',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Mock, self).__init__()


    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        if name in ('__file__', '__path__'):
            return os.devnull
        else:
            return Mock

    @classmethod
    def __setattr__(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __setitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return

    def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Mock
```

The `__all__` is required to allow `from x import *` style imports for the PyQt5 classes.

I can confirm that changing the superclass to `object` results in the classes being correctly documented, as does remove the Mock (generating locally). Forcing the documentation by using `:autoclass:` results in a single line saying that the class inherits from `Mock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this in the end by not using `Mock` for `Qt` objects. In my application there is a `qt.py` wrapper file that handles differences between `PyQt4` and `PyQt5` and allows them to be subsequently imported for use (while ignoring the `Qt` namespace rearrangement).

In this file I wrapped the actual import code in a test for ReadTheDocs and then if detected returned a series of dummy classes inheriting directly from `object`. Additions were required where objects have attributes, but this is only used once in the code base. It'll need to be kept up to date, but it solves the problem.

```
# ReadTheDocs
ON_RTD = os.environ.get('READTHEDOCS', None) == 'True'
if not ON_RTD:

    #... do the normal import here ...

else:

    class QMockObject(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(QMockObject, self).__init__()

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return None

    class QApplication(QMockObject):
        pass

    class pyqtSignal(QMockObject):
        pass

    class pyqtSlot(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QObject(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QAbstractItemModel(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QModelIndex(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QTabWidget(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QWebPage(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QTableView(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QWebView(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QAbstractTableModel(QMockObject):
        pass

    class Qt(QMockObject):
        DisplayRole = None

    class QWidget(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QPushButton(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QDoubleSpinBox(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QListWidget(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QDialog(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QSize(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QTableWidget(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QMainWindow(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QTreeWidget(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QAbstractItemDelegate(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QColor(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QGraphicsItemGroup(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QGraphicsItem(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QGraphicsPathItem(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QGraphicsTextItem(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QGraphicsRectItem(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QGraphicsScene(QMockObject):
        pass

    class QGraphicsView(QMockObject):
        pass

    app = None
```