# Sphinx failed to autodoc classes that inherits from a Mock-ed class

Tags: python, inheritance, mocking, python-sphinx

I'm trying to document a module with Sphinx and auto-document extension. I have some libraries that cannot be imported with standard python (they came from a very complicated in-house framework for Maya). I have mock-ed out this modules, and everything work as expected except for any class that inherits from a Mock-ed class. This classes didn't appear in the resulting documentation.

This is the way I have mock-ed my modules (this code lies inside `conf.py`):

```
for mod in MODULE_LIST:
    sys.modules[mod] = mock.MagicMock()
```

I have already read this question [Sphinx-doc :automodule: with Mock imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960309/sphinx-doc-automodule-with-mock-imports), but I can't implement the accepted solution because we have a huge number of modules.

Is there any way to make Sphinx ignore inheritance of the mock-ed modules?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [autodoc a class that extends a mocked class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893614/autodoc-a-class-that-extends-a-mocked-class)